# Run a vim command from a python script

Tags: python, linux, bash, vim

I have configured a keyboard shortcut using xbindkeys to run a python script.

Now, while editing any vim file if that user press that keyboard shortcut-

- I want my python script to run this command to paste the path and line no to the system clipboard-

  `:let @+=expand("%") . ':' . line(".")`
- Then I want my script to copy that path from the system clipboard and process it further

Can you please suggest me a good solution for this.
Thanks In advance

Comment: If you want copy to the system clipboard then you could use this command `os.system("echo 'hello world' | pbcopy")`

Comment: @kylek Thanks for replying, any idea about the first part, that is more important to me.

Comment: @kylek i am on linux and this worked for me [link](http://www.answermysearches.com/python-how-to-copy-and-paste-to-the-clipboard-in-linux/286/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works on my machine (OSX):

```
function! CopyToClipboard()
    py << EOF
import vim, os
# evaluate a vim expression and save its value to a variable
path_line = vim.eval('expand("%") . ":" . line(".")')
# copy the string to the clipboard
os.system("echo '%s' | pbcopy" % path_line)

# do additional stuff with path_line here

EOF
endfunction
```

An example keybinding:

```
nnoremap ,c :call CopyToClipboard()<CR>
```

Have a look at this link for further information on the python/vim interface:
http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/if_pyth.html and, of course, `:h python`.

If your script is quite long, I would recommend putting everything in separate python-only files.

```
:h pyfile
```

Should help in this case.

Comment: Can I invoke this script using a keyboard shortcut say using ctrl + shift + e or i can invoke it from vim only.
And where did you place this file and what extension did you used .py ?

Comment: You can invoke it with a keybinding from within vim. You could place the function (and the keybinding) in your .vimrc. If you place it in a file with file extension `.vim`, you just have to make sure vim reads (sources) the file on startup. See `:h source`. As I said, you can put the python only code inside a `.py` file and load it with `pyfile`.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using Vim's Python API, not an external Python script. see `:h python`. You can access all that info directly through its functions. You can evaluate a vim command with `vim.command()` to interface with the clipboard.

There are other ways to get at the clipboard using e.g. PyGTK, or perhaps more directly through `python-xlib`, but would probably be more difficult.